# to change the height of second div according to the height of first div in which the first div height is dynamic

Tags: html

I have two divs .I want the height of the second div same as that of the first div in which the height of first div is dynamic.I have applied display table for the row containing it and table-cell for the two columns.But it doesn't works for me can anyone help me with this.

```
code 
<div class="row" style="display: table;">
     <div class=" col-md-8" style="display: table-cell;"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4" style="display: table-cell;">
</div>
```

Comment: i guess you forgot to close one of col div

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works well.

```html
<div class="row" style="display: table;background-color:#000">
     <div class=" col-md-8" style="display: table-cell;background-color:#f00">
       AA<br>
       AA<br>
       AA<br>
       AA<br>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" style="display: table-cell;background-color:#0f0">BB<div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have two buttons in the 8  column div and bill design in the 4 column.On the button click it shows some hidden divs so the height of the 8  column div increases but the height of second div remains fixed